# RxJs 6 - React to concatMap in filter or takeWhile condition

Tags: angular, observable, reactive-programming, rxjs6

I use concatMap to do two API calls consecutively, but the second one should only be run if a checkbox is checked. So this is my code:

```
this.myService.createArticle(article)
  .pipe(
    filter(() => this.checkbox),
    concatMap(() => return this.mailer.createOtherResource(data)),
  }).subscribe(
    (x) => { console.log('OK', x); },
    error => console.error('FALLA', error),
    () => console.log('Finally I have really reached the END')
  );
```

The thing is that, if the check box is not checked, even if the first observable does not return an error, the OK function is never run, only the 'finally' one, and I need it to inform the user that the resource was created. What can I do?

I tried with `takeWhile` instead `pipe`, and same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last callback of your subscribe is ran only for the second call. If you want the first HTTP call to call a method once done, try this :

```
this.myService.createArticle(article)
  .pipe(
    finalize(() => console.log('Finally I have really reached the END (of the first call)'))
    filter(() => this.checkbox),
    concatMap(() => return this.mailer.createOtherResource(data)),
  }).subscribe(
    (x) => { console.log('OK', x); },
    error => console.error('FALLA', error),
    () => console.log('Finally I have really reached the END')
  );
```

Comment: Thanks! The thing is that the first finalize will run if the first observable returns ok or there's an error, wouldn't it? I would like to differentiate that.

Comment: Well you can use `catchError` for the error and `tap` for the success : this way, you can remove the finalize, which would be triggered anyway !

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Pizzicato just remember ti put the `tap` **after** the `catchError` : `tap` does something anyway, but if an error occurs, your stream should stop and prevent it from doing its thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's returned by your `createOtherResource` function but is it an Observable ?

Maybe you should try this :

```
this.myService.createArticle(article)
  .pipe(
    filter(() => this.checkbox),
    concatMap(() => of(this.mailer.createOtherResource(data))),
  })
  .subscribe(
    (x) => console.log('OK', x),
    error => console.error('FALLA', error),
    () => console.log('Finally I have really reached the END')
  );
```

Comment: Yes, it returns an observable, no need for of operator